# react native parsing Lottie file into state?

Tags: animation, react-native, jsx, lottie

I am trying to implement Lottie animation into my app, i am using expo SDK, 
so i followed the documentation on expo,

```
_loadAnimationAsync = async () => {
let result = await fetch(
  'https://cdn.rawgit.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native/635163550b9689529bfffb77e489e4174516f1c0/example/animations/Watermelon.json'
);

this.setState(
  { animation: JSON.parse(result._bodyText) },
  this._playAnimation
);
```

};

i got an [Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"].

is it result ._bodyText who is empty or undefined ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just meet the same issue and fixed.

modify `_loadAnimationAsync` should get it work.

```
_loadAnimationAsync = async () => {
let result = await fetch(
  'https://cdn.rawgit.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native/635163550b9689529bfffb77e489e4174516f1c0/example/animations/Watermelon.json'
)
  .then(data => {
    return data.json();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
this.setState({ animation: result }, this._playAnimation);
};
```

I also start a pr for this issue if you are interested. [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-docs/issues/297)